# RESTful API: How to handle translated textfields in representations?

Tags: api, rest, translation

I am designing a RESTful API for a booking application. There are accommodations that you can request a list or the details. As the application targets a multi-language audience, the descriptions are (sometimes) available in different languages.

Now I'm not sure how to handle these translations in the representation of an accommodation. Without the multiple languages I would make "description" a field or the accommodation object, quite simple.

Any idea how to solve this elegantly?

My current idea: Add a list of descriptions with text<->culture pairs instead of the description field and an additional subressource `/descriptions` to the accommodation for the creating (POST), updating (PUT) and deleting (DELETE) of new translations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For retrieving the representations in the appropriate language you simply set the Accept-Language HTTP header.

*Request*:

```
GET /Hotel/345
Accept-Language: fr
```

*Response*:

```
<Hotel>
  <Description xml:lang='fr'>Ce edifice est magnifique</Description>
</Hotel>
```

For doing the updates you could just include multiple description elements, assuming you are using xml as your media type format.

*Request*:

```
PUT /Hotel/345

<Hotel>
  <Description xml:lang='en'>This building is magnificent</Description>
  <Description xml:lang='fr'>Ce edifice est magnifique</Description>
</Hotel>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I hoped for but there is a requirement to deliver the description in multiple languages, Accept-Language is not an option. Your XML looks good though, shouldn't there be a "<Descriptions>" around the two descriptions?

Comment: There does not need to be a "Descriptions" element containing the single Descriptions, that is completely up to you.  If you don't want to use the Accept-Language, the GET can return the same document that I used for the PUT.  That way you can return as many languages as you like.